# Session Not Being Set

Tags: php, html, wordpress, session

I have the following code, but for some reason the session is staying empty.

Can someone help sort out this issue?

```
<?php

session_start();

ob_start();

$ifLogged = $_SESSION["mbse"];

if(!isset($ifLogged))
{
    $_SESSION["mbse"] = 'not logged';
}

echo '--'.$ifLogged.'--';

//Obtain Info if User Tried to Log In
$username = $_POST[username];
$password = $_POST[password];
$submit = $_POST[submit];

if(isset($submit))
{

    $_SESSION["mbse"] = $username;

    $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );
    if ( $user && wp_check_password( $password, $user->data->user_pass, $user->ID) )
    {

        // Automatic login //
        $user = get_user_by('login', $username );

        // Redirect URL //
        if ( !is_wp_error( $user ) )
        {
            wp_clear_auth_cookie();
            wp_set_current_user ( $user->ID );
            wp_set_auth_cookie  ( $user->ID );

            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/landing-page" />';


            exit();
        }
        else
        { echo 'Error';}
        //Stop Here
    }
    else
    {
       echo "Username and Passcode Do Not Match";
    }
}

//Obtain Domain and Check Alias
$domain = "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
$alias = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

//Strip the Slashes from the Alias

$alias = str_replace("/", "", $alias);

if($alias == '')
{
    $nameInput = 'text';
}
else
{
    $nameInput = 'hidden';
}


echo'

<form method="POST">
 <div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" type="'.$nameInput.'" value="'.$alias.'" name="username" placeholder="Input Your Username" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Input Your Password"  required />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12  submitlogin">
<input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
</form>';
```

Both from the next pages, and when I return to this page - the session is initially empty and after first attemtp it shows 'not logged'. The thing is that the condition is being trigerred as the redirection is happening.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Try `if(empty($_SESSION['mbse']))`. Why do people insist on moving perfectly good array values into unnecessary scalar variables?

Comment: I have done this change but I don't think it's the issue. The session when authenticating is not being stored for some reason.

Comment: Yes, confirmed. The statement $_SESSION["mbse"] = $username; is never being executed.

Answer (score 0):

spotted it, that took longer than it should have, sorry

The array keys need to be wrapped in quotes like this

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
```

Comment: I have added a trigger right after I set the session, and to output what is stored. The value is displaying correctly. So if I set $username as 'test' the js alert is showing 'Trigerred test'. However, the session variable appears to not be stored as in subsequent pages this is lost again.